# growable array programmatically

Tags: java, oracle

I have a db table (sample) with one column (name), I want to read records from that table and store them in an array (I don't want to go for collections kind of thing). I want my array size to grow dynamically. Can anyone fix my Java code?
I'm posting my code here.

```
public class ArrayEx {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String str[]=new String[4];
    int i=-1;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","sasi","admin");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select name from sample");
    while(rs.next()){
        i++;

        str[i]=rs.getString("name");
    }
    for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(str[j]+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid you have to "go for collections kind of thing". Using collections is not difficult, don't worry about that.

Comment: I know collections is easy.but my requirement is, i have to go with arrays only.anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: Then perform two queries: one to get the count to calculate how many items you will retrieve, which will mark the size of your array, and another query where you get the data and populate the array. Still, this is a very odd design and a bad requirement.

Comment: @user2949291 an Array that grows dynamically, as you require, is an ArrayList. An Array does not change its size at runtime.

Comment: You could, when your array is full, create a new array with maybe double the size of the previous array and copy the contents of the old array to it. Because arrays are fixed in size, so you can't let them grow dynamicly.

Comment: @WonderWorld yes,that is my requirement.But some how i'm stuck with the code.i'm unable to code it.could you help me with that?

Comment: @user2949291 someone already posted an answer to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array which grows, use an ArrayList. Otherwise, you could determine the number of rows up front and use an array.

```
Statement st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select name from sample");
rs.last();
int lastRow = rs.getRow();
String str[]=new String[lastRow-1];
rs.beforeFirst();
while (rs.next()) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This will not work unless you create a SCROLL_INSENSITIVE statement.

Answer (score 1):

Using Collections is the Best way. But,since you dont want you use Collection, you can do some thing like this.

In the First just declare the Array like

String str[];

Once you have Executed the Query and got the Resultset, then you can dynamically assign the value for the str using the size of the Resultset.

str=new[ResultSet_size];

But this is a very old and poor coding technique.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you really want to use a "growing" array, it would look like this:

```
int capcity = 4;
int usedSlots = 0;
String growingArray[] = new String[capcity];
```

Now you "just" keep increasing "usedSlots" every time you store a value in your array. If "usedSlots" reaches the current "capacity"; you can increase the capacity, create a new array, copy over all existing array elements ... and so on. But as others have pointed out - there is no need to grow the array, if the maximum number of required elements is known in advance. On the other hand, if that number is not known, then using arrays is plain wrong.

You see - unless we are talking about classes for your homework, your requirement to not use Collections is, well ... "stupid". Its like asking a carpenter to connect some objects with nails; but please without using a hammer.

Simply spoken: it does not make sense; you gain nothing from not using Collections. Actually, you "gain" code that will be harder to understand and maintain (and that might cause quite some negative feedback to you when you present this code in a review to your peers).

Answer (score 1):

That's not object oriented and looks like a small `C` exercise. Anyway, there is very few modification for your code to work:
Note: `Arrays.copyOf()` allocate a new array of the specified size and copy the elements of the original one. You may want to do this manually too...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int incSize = 4; // will increase the array of this size when needed
    String str[]=new String[incSize];
    int i=0; // keeps count of nb of occupied slots

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","sasi","admin");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select name from sample");
    while(rs.next()){
        // If we reach the end of the array, let's increase it
        if (i == str.length) {
            str = Arrays.copyOf(str, str.length+incSize);
        }
        str[i] = rs.getString("name");
        i++;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(str[j]+" ");
    }
}
```